# How to filter the result of (page.$$eval)

Tags: node.js, puppeteer

I'm using the following code to select all hrefs from a web page:

```
const hrefs = await page.$$eval('a', as => as.map(a => a.href));
```

I need to know how to filter those hrefs with the ones that only contains /product/ & contains /c/ for example?

Answer (score 2):

You can add [`Array.prototype.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) with [`String.prototype.includes()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes) predicates:

```js
const hrefs = await page.$$eval(
  'a',
  as => as.map(a => a.href)
          .filter(href => href.includes('/product/') && href.includes('/c/'))
);
```

Comment: How to retrieve the all the `as` instead of `hrefs` using same filter condition?

Comment: @Prem Try `const links = await page.$$eval(
  'a',
  as => as.filter(a => a.href.includes('/product/') && a.href.includes('/c/'))
);` — you will get an array with `ElementHandle`s

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by using .filter instead of .map method.

Here is what you can try:

```
const hrefs = await page.$$eval('a', as => as.filter((d)=>{
                return (d.contains('/c/') && d.contains('/product/'))
              }));
```